# Print PID to file

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, pid, io-redirection

I'm trying to make a bash script to be run in a terminal that prints its own **PID** to a .txt file at the beginning of the script.

I know that you get the PID of a responsive terminal by typing in `$$`, but if I do it, the PID gets automatically executed and therefore the output is not the PID, but `bash:PIDNUMVALUE: command not found`, and if I print the output of `$$` into a .txt file, the output will not be the PID, but `bash:PIDNUMVALUE: command not found` while I only want the PID to be printed in the txt file.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo $$ > my.pid
```

Or use `$BASHPID` instead for better script readability IMO, but keep in mind some subtle differences between the two:

> Expands to the process ID of the current Bash process. This differs from `$$` under certain circumstances, such as subshells that do not require Bash to be re-initialized.

Check [the Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables) for further information.